# How to properly bind data from Web API to ListBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have an ASP.NET Web API which works all fine according to my tests. Now, I want to consume it in a simple WPF application. I just want to get the data from API, display it in the client app, and then to add or delete the data from the database just by using the client app.

My problem is that when I pass the data to a `ListBox`, I kind of lose information, specifically I lose the `Id` of the object, which I need later in order to delete it from the database. In my scenario, I have something like this in one of my pages:

```
<ListBox
    Name="carCategoryListBox"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1" />
```

And then, in the `.cs` file of the page, I do something like this:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BindCarCategoryList();
}

private async void BindCarCategoryList()
{
    var client = CarHttpClient.GetClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/carcategories");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var carCategories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DTO.CarCategory>>(content);

        carCategoryListBox.ItemsSource = carCategories.Select(cc => cc.Category).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error code " + response.StatusCode + "\nMessage - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
        return;
    }
}
```

As you can see I just get the `Category` fields of my objects, and pass them to the `ListBox` to be displayed. The `CarCategory` class is pretty simple and can be seen below:

```
public class CarCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that at a later stage I need to get the actual `Id` of the object, and use it. But, since I pass only the `Category` field to the `ListBox`, this `Id` information is somehow lost in my case. If I do something like this:

```
int id = carCategoryListBox.SelectedIndex;
```

Then, I just get the `Id` of the item in the `ListBox` (which item it is in the list), I don't actually get the original `Id` of the object that is stored in the database. Any ideas how to pass the data to a `ListBox` in such a way that I still somehow preserve the original `Id` information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListBox.SelectedIndex` is a position of selected item in ItemsSource. It can even be -1 if there is no selected item. And it is not the same value as `Id`

to get databound object make some changes:

1) use `List<CarCategory>` as ItemsSource:

```
carCategoryListBox.ItemsSource = carCategories;
```

2) set ListBox.DisplayMemberPath for it to display category name:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Category"
    Name="carCategoryListBox"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1" />
```

3) use `SelectedItem` property to get selected item (can be `null`):

```
var category = (CarCategory)carCategoryListBox.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the entire object not select just a field from it, and set the list box's DisplayMemberPath to 'Category'. Then your selected item will be the entire CarCategory, and you can get its ID.

You should also look at MVVM and try to get as close as possible to the concepts, they really help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your BindCarCategoryList

```
carCategoryListBox.ItemsSource = carCategories.Select(cc => cc.Category).ToList();
```

to

```
carCategoryListBox.ItemsSource = carCategories;
```

and modify your xaml like this

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" Width="250" DisplayMemberPath="Category" DisplayMemberPath="Id" />
```

or if you dont use MVVM assign DisplayMemberPath and DisplayMemberPath directly in your .cs file